# Rails, js response, only a notice

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my rails app I would like to prevent users from deleting a post given some conditions. When that happens, I would like to just inform them that the post could not be deleted. The code looks like this:

```
def destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    if some_conditions
      flash[:notice] = "Could not be deleted"
      ...
      format.js {What to put here}
    else
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

What should I put in the js response brackets so that the page is not reloaded but the notice is displayed? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just first, leave the format.js as it is, we will work this from the js file.

```
def destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    if some_conditions
      flash[:notice] = "Could not be deleted"
      format.js 
    else
    end
  end
end
```

Now create a file named **destroy.js.erb in app/views/your controller** name

in that file, `destroy.js.erb`

`alert("Could not be deleted")`

or if you want to display your notice,

take a div in your view file,

`<div class="something"></div>`

in your js.erb,

`$('.something').text(<%= flash[:notice] %> )`

Comment: I get an error message "Missing template posts/destroy". Oh, I forgot the destroy.js.erb...

Comment: have you added js.erb

Answer (score 2):

You can put the flash inside like so `format.js { flash[:notice] = "Could not be deleted" }` and it would compile the same. To print the notice: create a destroy.js.erb as Sravan pointed out.

create a `div with a class="errors"`

append the flash[:notice] by:

```
$('.errors').append("<%= flash[:notice] %>")
```

Comment: Do I need the destroy.js.erb?